# How to invoke JS function from Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to invoke JS method from Android level. 
I created @JavascriptInterface. In the method of the WebViewClient class, I injected the JS script with the JS function which is calling Android interface method in Java (I injected it in `WebViewClient @Override onPageFinished` method)

Now from the JS level (by injecting it) I can run the Android method.
But I want also inform html page to reload by JS script - by changing URL hash (#fragment).
I mean, I want to call from the Android level the JS method of the html page, 
specifically `javascript: window.location.replace = ...` or `window.location.hash = ...`

Is this even possible?

Comment: it takes about 30 seconds to find how to `android webview run js` in google

Comment: True, it turned out that there was a problem with threads. Handler.post () resolved the problem of invoking the js method.